# Прибавление к дате в datetimelocal определённое количество дней и к времени определённое количество часов через JS

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть два объекта `<input type="datetime-local" name="startofvalidityperiod" class="form form-control form-control-lg" required="" id="id_startofvalidityperiod">` и `<input type="datetime-local" name="expirationdate" class="form-control form-control-lg form" readonly="0" id="id_expirationdate">`. В скрипте JS у меня есть событие, которое отслеживает выбор даты в первом объекте

```
window.onload = function() {
    let date = document.getElementById('id_startofvalidityperiod');
    date.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        alert(date);
    });
}
```

Мне необходимо к дате, которая выбрана в первом объекте прибавить определённое количество дней, а ко времени прибавить определённое количество часов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь автоисправлением даты.
В объект `Date` можно установить (`set`) 32 число, и внутренний парсер сам сдвинет месяц на следующий, а число на 1ое или 2ое или 4(февраль) или 3 (февраль високосного года)

```
const datePlusDays = (date, days) => {
  let newDate = new Date(date);
  const curDateNum = date.getDate();
  newDate.setDate(curDateNum + Number(days));
  return newDate;
};

const datePlusHours = (date, hours) => {
  let newDate = new Date(date);
  const curHoursNum = date.getHours();
  newDate.setHours(curHoursNum + hours(days));
  return newDate;
}

const datePlusDaysAndHours = (date, days, hours) => {
  let newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate = datePlusDays(newDate, days);
  newDate = datePlusHours(newDate, hours);
  return newDate;
}
```

не сокращайте код! попытки сделать это в стиле `return date.setDate(date.getDate()+days)` приведут к выдаче `timestamp` (количество микросекунд), а вам нужен нормальный объект даты.

*Справочная информация:*

1. [Учебник](https://learn.javascript.ru/date)
2. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
3. [Стандарт ECMA-262.11](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-overview-of-date-objects-and-definitions-of-abstract-operations)

Comment: А как можно получить дату из поля и вывести её? Я пробовал вот таким способом          var datestart = document.getElementById('id_startofvalidityperiod');
         let newDate = new Date(datestart);
         console.log(newDate); Но при таком подходе выдаётся ошибка Invalid date. Предполагаю, что её надо как-то парсить

Comment: Илья, почитайте учебник и если хватит упорства, спецификацию, это ответит на многие вопросы. Например, что дату нельзя ввести в произвольном формате. Внутренний парсер сам всё отпарсит, если дата будет введена в одном из доступных ему форматов, например '2021.3.27'. (продолжу в следующем комменте)

Comment: Заставить пользователя вводить дату только в подходящих форматах можно двумя способами. 1. Сделать 3 поля для года, месяца и числа. Написать валидатор, который будет на основе регулярных выражений стирать всякие буквы, не давать вводить всякую ересь вроде нулевого года нашей эры и т.д. Это запарно, но я такое делал. Продолжу ниже

Comment: Второй способ простой - взять готовую форму из html стандарта <input type="date"> https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date . Нужно так же назначить ему id и брать у элемента его value. Он гарантированно будет в формате 'yyyy-mm-dd', который распарсится JS без проблем. Правда в каждом браузере такой инпут выглядит по разному. Чтобы было одинаково -- надо писать свой ввод с нуля.

Comment: У меня type=datetime-local. Там сразу и дата и время

Comment: Так суйте в `new Date()` `value`. Вы то целиком элемент засовываете. Вы делаете так: `var datestart = document.getElementById('id_startofvalidityperiod'); let newDate = new Date(datestart); ` А надо так: `const datestart = document.getElementById('id_startofvalidityperiod').value; let newDate = new Date(datestart);` Видите разницу? *`.value`* у элемента c input

Comment: Илья, не пренебрегайте справочной информацией, там всё написано. Это экономит время: ответы из справки получить быстрее чем дождаться ответа от других людей. А если вопрос сложный/очень частный, то подчас и вовсе ответа не дождаться ) А в справке сразу всё написано, даже с примером применения.

Comment: Спасибо большое за вашу помощь. Прочитав учебник и ваши комментарии разобрался и смог получить и прибавить к дате нужное количество дней. Но как мне теперь присвоить полученную дату и время новому элементу? Она у меня вот в таком формате Thu Mar 31 2022 13:10:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время). Пробовал через $("#dateend").val(newDate);

Comment: На самом деле она у вас получается в формате экзмпляра класса `Date`. И у него кууууча методов, в том числе методов получения отдельных компонентов даты. `newDate.getFullYear()`, `newDate.getMonth()`, `newDate.getDate()` и т.д. Надо получить строчку? Соберите строчку из этих частей `'let finalDateStr = newDate.getFullYear() + ' год ' + (newDate.getMonth()+1) + 'месяц'....` и т.д.

Comment: У меня есть второй такой же объект с типом datetime-local. Мне надо в него засунуть эту дату в формате по типу 31.12.2021 13:32

Comment: У `datetime-local` нет поддержки 'valueAsDate' Смотрите таблицу: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#input-type-attr-summary . Всё что вы можете, это передать туда строку с точным форматированием `1970-01-01T00:00:00.0 ` обязательно с нулями. Вот аналогичный вопрос с ответами и кодом как это сделать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166338/setting-value-of-datetime-local-from-date Поиск на английском выдаёт гораздо больше чем на русском.